# Passing an Object in to another component blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

hey im struggling with my blazor project.

I have a file called LoginCode.razor.cs
I make an HTTP request and receive a response. The response is a JSON that I deserialize and wrote to an object called ResponseData.
I want to call this object in another Razor component called SecondMain.razor and display the data that came back as a response.

I already tried to transfer the object using the NavigationManager by passing it to the NavigateTo method but this dont work because the NavigationManager can't transfer objects.
How can I use the object from the first component in the second component?
This is my json

```
{"success":{"code":22,"message":"Authentication 
succeeded","data":"some 
data","timetolive":86400,"mobilenumber":null}}
```

And this is my ResposneData class

```
namespace AdminFrontend.Services
{
public class ResponseData
{
public SuccessData success { get; set; }

public ErrorData error { get; set; }

 }

public class SuccessData
{
public int code { get; set; }
public string message { get; set; }
public string data { get; set; }
public int timetolive { get; set; }
public int mobilenumber { get; set; }

}

public class ErrorData
{
public int code { get; set; }
public string message { get; set; }
public string data { get; set; }
public int timetolive { get; set; }
public object mobilenumber { get; set; }
}
}
```

At the moment im trying something like this

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var antwort = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
try
{
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  var responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseData> 
                                                  (antwort);
     // Login succees;
            id = Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode);
            LoginApi loginApi = new LoginApi(id, antwort);

            _loginErrorMessages = loginApi.GetMessage();
            await InvokeAsync(() => appState.LoggedIn = true);
            navigationManager.NavigateTo
                              ($"/secondMain, {responseData}");

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            
            LoginApi loginApi = new LoginApi(id, antwort);
            _loginErrorMessages = loginApi.GetMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Several possibilities: send the data as URL parameters, save it in browser storage, save it in a DB, and more... Browser Storage would probably be your best choice here: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server).

Comment: Use a Scoped service to get and hold the data.  Inject the service into any components that need access to it.